# SharePoint Designer customized approval workflow- look up help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am building a customized approval workflow.  When the email is sent to the approver there is a link within the email that will direct the approver straight to the form that was filled out by the initiator.  I cannot duplicate that link in designer.  I tried to duplicate this Lookup in a different email and it didnt work.  I even tried to look it up in Edit Hyperlink.

[%Task Process:Item Title%].

Lookup for String:
Data Source: Task Process: Food Request
Field from Source: Item Title
Return field as: String

Edit Hyperlink:
Text to Display: [%Task Process:Item Title%]
Address: [%Task Process:Web URL%]/[%Task Process:Item URL%]